# How to get rid of order by or optimize the query

Tags: php, mysql

I have got query

```
select field from table order by field asc limit 4000, 30;
```

Table has got million rows order by on such simple select make big delays. There is index on field.
How to get rid of 'order by' and speed up the limit and obtain the same result via select?

My proposition is to change the order of rows and then just make simple `select field from table`. Could you suggest better idea?

Comment: Would using a system of indexes work?

Comment: Do you order by different fields?  Or do you just want to order by the same field every time?

Comment: Could you add a `int` column `order` and try sorting on that?

Comment: @Newbie1: so you need to select all million rows? For what?

Comment: Is there a need to display all the million rows results? You can add LIMIT on your query to speed up the query and display if there is not a need to display all results.

Comment: Yes, there is index on 'field'. I am ordering by one field. I tried int but seem to have similar result. I need to select only 30 records and paginate the rest (I am using limit 30). Problem is when the offset is for example 4000 then query takes many second, this way it can't go online :(

Comment: @Newbie1: this happens because to find 4001st row mysql ought to iterate row by row. The only possible solution that could help is to use only fixed size types in this table and change row type to `FIXED`

Comment: @zerkms The difference really only matters for MyISAM when it comes to row type, other storage engines do not care about the difference. I am using InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

The data type of a field has an effect on how fast order by will be.  Integer columns are generally fastest for this, and text columns the slowest.  If the datatype of the column you're sorting by is textual I'd suggest using a numeric column for ordering instead.

Indexing the column you're ordering by should help performance, but MySQL might ignore it and do a full table scan.  FORCE INDEX might be of benefit in speeding up the sorting.

Changing the physical order of the columns in the table will not have a predictable effect, as default ordering for rows is not defined in MySQL, or indeed any SQL database that I know of.  As rows get added, altered and deleted, the physical position of the row in the table will change over time so you can't depend on it for ordering.

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/ has some useful tips on optimizing sorts.

Comment: Good article, but didn't help to solve my problem. I can't use between, there is already index on integer. Is the cache one and the only solution?